# Arduino communication with C# and connection drop detection

Tags: c#, arduino

I am making simple app in C# and connecting Arduino Mega over USB and opening serial communication between them. I can send and receive data from  Arduino.

I've spent last 3 days digging around how to make Arduino Mega to detect lost connection with C# and turn LED on for instance. When C# is opened, it opens Serial communication with Arduino. When I terminate C# application, LED on arduino should turn on to indicate that Serial communication is dropped.

I have tried several options `Serial.available()` on arduino side but that led to nowhere.

Does anyone have any suggestion(s)?

Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to implement some kind of keepalive every few seconds. I don't think there is a possible way to detect the state of a serial connection if no data is sent.

Comment: I was thinking the same; sort of pin-pong and if pong is missed 2x then connection is dropped. I am wondering what's the best way to implement it